# Parallax background layers still moving when player is blocked by some object

Tags: android, libgdx, box2d

Developing my first game in libgdx and i just started with Box2d physics.

I have 6 layered parallax background.. and its works fine

The problem is layers of my parallax background are still moving when my character is blocked by some object and left or right button is still pressed.

i tried with ContactactListerner to identify collision but it not works

:::::::::::::::: Here is the Explanation code ::::::::::::::

one of my parallax background layer

```
sb.draw(treesBack, treesBackX, 0, width / Hunter.PPM, height / Hunter.PPM, 
uRight, vTop, 0, 0);
```

handleInput CODE :

```
//if right button pressed
    if((hud.BUTTON_R == true) && (player.b2body.getLinearVelocity().x <= 2)){
        player.b2body.applyLinearImpulse(new Vector2(1f, 0),  
        player.b2body.getWorldCenter(), true);
        if(colliding != true){
            treesBackX -= 1 * dt;
        }
    }
```

ContactListener Code :

```
public boolean colliding = false;

@Override
public void beginContact(Contact contact) {
    Fixture fixA = contact.getFixtureA();
    Fixture fixB = contact.getFixtureB();

    if(fixA.getUserData() == "side" || fixB.getUserData() == "side"){
        Fixture side = fixA.getUserData() == "side" ? fixA : fixB;
        Fixture object = side == fixA ? fixB : fixA;

        if(object.getUserData() != null){
            colliding = true;
            Gdx.app.log("Side Collision", "True");
        }

    }

}
```

Please help me..! i searched a lot but never found any exact solution.
Your help will keeps my project alive, otherwise i have to close this project.

Thank you, and Sorry for bad english..

Comment: YEESSSSSSS.....

Comment: Problem solved! I made my own logic. Thank you for reply;